# To navbar will not fit fully on left and right

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I don't want to have the space on the left and right of `#navbar` is there a way i could do this with `margin` or `margin-left`/`margin-right`

Comment: Pretty hard to tell you for sure without us seeing code &/or a working JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
#navbar{float:left;width:100%;margin:0}
```

if you dont want 100% width just remove it

Answer (score 0):

`#navbar{padding:0;margin:0;}`

also look for the your parent div check whether they have any padding or margin apply to it.

honestly, it is hard to answer your question as it is too open.